# Can I automatically update my Intellij project to use the latest snapshot using gradle?

Tags: intellij-idea, jenkins, gradle, artifactory

Is there a way to get IntelliJ to automatically update to the newest snapshot of a dependency using gradle?

I currently have two projects, A and B. A is a library that B uses. I am developing them both from scratch at the same time.

I have a Jenkins build that checks out the code from a development branch, runs the gradle build script, and then publish the artifact to my snapshot artifactory repository.

My `build.gradle` is set to use integration.latest from my snapshot repository but IntelliJ will not pull in the changes automatically. I have to go to jetgradle, click refresh and then import the new snapshot and then remove the previous snapshot.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Could you give some more info? Are you using gradle idea plugin (else that would probably be your answer). What do you mean by "jetgradle, click refresh"

Comment: I am using the gradle idea plugin. There is a side panel labeled as JetGradle, the refresh button is top left: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/resolving-dependencies.html  When I click refresh my snapshot dependency shows up as green and I have to right click and click import in order to actually pull the library in. I am creating a snapshot of my library, incrementing the  snapshot version number. I then click refresh and my new version shows up as green, ready to be pulled in but the old one remains.

Comment: looking at intellij docs, it appears that you currently cannot do that (tho i may be wrong). i had the same problem before that forced me to switch to gradle idea plugin instead (generating idea settings files). maybe intellij 12 will make it more flexible.

Comment: I'm almost certain that you still have to manually regenerate the idea project files in 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like there is not a way to pull in the latest snapshot automatically. I wanted to have nicely modularized library projects but still actively develop them at the same time I was working on projects that depended on them.

I ended up creating a main project with its own build.gradle. I then added git submodules for my library projects.

This allows me to have separated library projects that I can reuse but also a fast development cycle as I don't have to wait for artifacts to get pushed to my artifactory server.

My Jenkins builds still pull artifacts from my artifactory server though.

Answer (score 0):

If you update local code in Project A and want to see them reflected in project B with A as dependency you should run `gradle install` on project A. (install is available on the IntelliJ task panel) Install will update the jar in the local maven repository and that will update IntelliJ with the latest code.